# What is wrong with this method for calculating the eigenvalues of $M$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the matrix:

$$M = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 3i \\ -3i &9 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 &9 \end{pmatrix} -3\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i \\ i &0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Now the first matrix on the right has eigenvalues $1$ and $9$, while the second matrix has eigenvalues $\pm1$. With the eigenvalue equation, one can write for some vector $u$:

$$Mu=\lambda u \ \to \ (\lambda_1 -3 \lambda_2)u=\lambda u \ \to \ \lambda_1 -3\lambda_2=\lambda $$

And therefore the eigenvalues should be $-2$ and $12$. However it's trivial to show directly that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $0$ and $10$. Can somebody spot what is the error here?

Comment: The eigenvector $u$ maybe an eigenvector for the first matrix, but not for the second one.

Comment: Ah of course... thank you

Comment: If $u$ is an eigenvector of $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 \\ 0 && 9 \end{bmatrix}$$ it doesn't have to an eigenvector of $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 && - i \\ i && 0 \end{bmatrix} $$